# Insertion sort not working - list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, insertion-sort

Trying to create insertion sort but receive an error...

Don't really know why it is happening. It always tends to miss 37 aswell

```
numbers = [45,56,37,79,46,18,90,81,50]

def insertionSort(items):
    Tsorted = []
    Tsorted.append(items[0])
    items.remove(items[0])
    for i in range(0,len(items)):
        print (Tsorted)
        if items[i] > Tsorted[len(Tsorted)-1]:
            Tsorted.append(items[i])
        else:
            Tsorted[len(Tsorted)-2] = items[i]
        items.remove(items[i])

insertionSort(numbers)
```

Error:

```
    if items[i] > Tsorted[len(Tsorted)-1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: These are not about your error. That already explained in answers but I wanted to add, `Tsorted.append(items.pop(items[0]))` is equal to what you are doing in those two line. Also, `Tsorted[-1]` will give you same result as `Tsorted[len(Tsorted)-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: you are removing items from the Array that you are iterating inside the loop here: `items.remove(items[i])`. This is generally not a good idea.

Second: This algorithm doesn't implement insertion sort, even if you fix the deletion issue. You should review the algorithm, e.g. here [Insertion sort in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). Thre is another loop required to find the right insertion place.

Third: in the else case, you are overwriting instead of inserting values.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing elements from `items` over the course of the loop; thus, `i` may become a value that was a valid index in the original `items`, but is no longer in the shortened one.

If you need to remove elements from `items`, it looks like you should wait until the loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're calling `tems.remove()`. Your code fails when i=4 and `items=[37, 46, 90, 50]`.

So they already has no an element with index `4` but with `3` since indexing starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

`range(0,len(items)` will only be calculated the first time your code hits your for-loop, at which state `len(list) = 8`. Which means that you wlil iterate

```
for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    #Do stuff...
```

But at the same time you remove items from your list in each loop. So when hitting i = 4, you have iterated your loop 4 times and the length of you `item`-list is only 4, which means that `items[4]`
 no longer exists.